# Adding string to each item in list?

Tags: string, mapping

So simple question, i'm not sure which function would be best to do this. How do you add a string to each item in a list? So example:

```
(setq list '("Sample Data" "More Fun"))
```

And then say I want to add " is great." to each item in my list so it reads:

```
(print list)
"Sample Data is great."
"More Fun is great."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mapping over lists is done with `mapcar`. Concatenating strings works in principle with `concat`. But, in most cases `mapconcat` is better.

```el
(setq list '("Sample Data" "More Fun"))

(setq list (mapcar (lambda (str)
                       (concat str " is great"))
                   list))
```

Example for `mapconcat`: Let us assume that you have given a variable `tail` with string value `"is great"`. The space before `is` is missing. `mapconcat` inserts the separator between the strings.

```el
(let ((list '("Sample Data" "More Fun"))
      (tail "is great"))

  (setq list (mapcar (lambda (str)
                        (mapconcat #'identity (list str tail) " "))
                     list)))
```

I also use a `let` form here instead of a simple `setq` avoiding the polution of the global namespace.